# IOException: COSStream has been closed and can not be read

Tags: pdfbox

I am using pdfbox 2.0.16 and getting IOException: COSStream has been closed and can not be read. Perhaps its enclosing PDDocument closed? intermittently while saving i.e. doc.save(fileName)/doc.save(byteArrayOutputStream).

I closed doc.close() properly in the finally block and i could not able to replicate locally but could observed on linux environment once in 10 times and not sure why.

can you please let us know any steps to resolve the issue.

Thanks,
Thiru
[image]

Comment: We don't see your code, so we can merely guess. One guess would be that you use material (pages, resources, whatever) from one PDF directly (without import) in another, and garbage collection can close the source document before you save the target document.

Comment: The current version is 2.0.24.

Comment: yes, @mkl i hope we are doing such scenarios. So how to handle such scenarios? We observed the same warnings(but not COSStream IOException) while we copy certain pdfs  and paste to another location (using File instance with path) even when we have not used apache pdfbox. So is it because of java GC? Please suggest certain steps.

Comment: Hi @TilmanHausherr, we can upgrade the version and i followed all of your steps specified in different posts to close the doc properly.  So does this upgrade can resolve the issue. https://github.com/danfickle/openhtmltopdf/issues/109

Comment: "the same warnings ... even when we have not used apache pdfbox" that makes no sense. And the link to PR 109 is about a change in openhtmltopdf (which uses pdfbox), not pdfbox itself.

Comment: *"So how to handle such scenarios?"* - essentially you have to make sure that the documents you take objects from remain open at least as long as the documents you add those objects to. This may require something like collecting the former ones,  and only after the latter ones have been closed also closing and freeing those collected former ones.

Comment: Hi @mkl, I am following the same steps. 1. I have a pdf A and I want to add couple of pages from another pdf B(PDDoc.load(filePath)) . So I have created content Stream on pdf A and each page of pdf B and transformed each page to A4 size (if not in A4 size), add the current page to pdf A, and then closed the content stream. This happens for each page of pdf b. So both content stream creation and close in the loop on the pages in pdf b. So we just loaded the pdf B but nothing to save or close i.e. its just reading the pages. After that, PDF A is going to be saved.Please suggest me changes if any

Comment: Don't close PDF B before saving PDF A. And keep a reference to B to avoid it getting closed due to garbage collection.

Comment: Do just like @Tilman says, prevent B from being closed before saving A. You might still get such log messages after saving, when closing the documents, but they should be harmless then. And if doing so you still have trouble, please provide a short piece of code to reproduce the issue with.

Comment: Hi @mkl, As you both suggested yes I am doing the same as said above **So we just loaded the pdf B but nothing to save or close i.e. its just reading the pages**. I added the code in the problem description. Please give your thoughts.

Comment: **A** please don'tpost code as a screen shot but instead in text form (you can format it as code by indenting or by enveloping in ```. **B** I said above *This may require something like collecting the former ones, and only after the latter ones have been closed also closing and freeing those collected former ones.* You now say *"I am doing the same"*. So where do you collect your `additionalDoc` instances to keep them from being closed by garbage collection before `doc.save`? Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/67168818/1729265